# Django/Wagtail - Custom form widget CSS/JS media not being rendered with template file

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a base `Address` model with a `formatted_address` field, which uses a custom `LocationPicker` widget (essentially an autocomplete for searching addresses).

A couple of classes inherit from `Address`, including my `Place` class below.

models.py

```
class Address(models.Model):
    formatted_address = models.CharField(max_length=500, verbose_name='address')
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Place(ClusterableModel, Address)
    ...

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('formatted_address', widget=LocationPicker(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search addresses')),
            FieldPanel('some_other_field')
        ], heading='My field group')
```

widgets.py

```
class LocationPicker(WidgetWithScript, TextInput):
    template_name = 'places/forms/widgets/location_picker.html'

    @property
    def media(self):
        print('get media')
        return Media(
            css={'screen': ('places/css/location-picker.css',)},
            js=('places/js/location-picker.js',),
        )
```

This widget appears fine in the Wagtail admin, where I have registered a `ModelAdmin` instance for it.

However, the problem I have is that I cannot get the widget to appear properly in my vanilla Django `ModelForm`. The widget template file is rendered, but the associated media is not included.

I have created the form as follows:

forms.py

```
class PlaceForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'formatted_address': LocationPicker(attrs={'placeholder': 'Search addresses')
        }
```

No matter what I've tried, the widget's media is not included when the form is rendered. The `'get media'` printout doesn't even appear.

I'm certain this can be done but I don't know what obvious thing I'm missing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to output `{{ form.media }}` (or `{{ form.media.js }}` and `{{ form.media.css }}`) somewhere on your template - this doesn't happen automatically on rendering the form itself.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I missed that. Was working along those lines but at the individual `{{ field.media }}` level. Been a while since I used form media! Thanks!